# Connecting to a remote zope console in windows ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, plone, zope

I followed this tutorial and installed Plone on a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS to play with.

http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/production/ubuntu_production.html

As per the tutorial I closed the ports, leaving opened only 22,80,443. As Zope Management is on port 8080 the documentation suggests creating a ssh tunnel:

```
ssh user@yourhostname.com -L:8080:localhost:8080
```

That works great when I'm on a Linux or Mac. How can I create the same connection on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get putty from http://www.putty.org/

Go to `Connection` -> `SSH` -> `Tunnles` and add configure the tunnel as shown in the following image.

[image]

Important hint! Click the `Add` Button after editing the tunnel settings and afterwards open.

You may use port 8080.

Comment: A nearly unrelated note: Microsoft has announced that ssh will be part of PowerShell in the first half of 2016.